# Menu design issue with Bootstrap

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3

I am using Bootstrap 3.2.0. It is very good to design, but now I am facing a problem to create menu like the following:

[image]

To design the menu, I have written code in [plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/hYovwFr0iKFCH1bRAcQl?p=preview) and here is my sample code:

```
<nav class="navbar navbar-inverse navbar-fixed-top" role="navigation">
        <div class="container-fluid">
            <div class="row">
                <ul class="topmenu">
                    <li class="topmenuItem"><a>HOME</a></li>
                    <li class="topmenuItem"><a>HOME</a></li>
                    <li class="topmenuItem"><a>HOME</a></li>
                    <li class="topmenuItem"><a>HOME</a></li>
                    <li class="topmenuItem"><a>HOME</a></li>
                </ul>
                <ul class="submenu">
                    <li class="submenuItem">
                        <ul class="submenuItemGroup">
                            <li class="submenuItemGroupItem"><a>SUBMENU</a></li>
                            <li class="submenuItemGroupItem"><a>SUBMENU</a></li>
                        </ul>
                    </li>
                    <li class="submenuItem">
                        <ul class="submenuItemGroup">
                            <li class="submenuItemGroupItem"><a>SUBMENU</a></li>
                            <li class="submenuItemGroupItem"><a>SUBMENU</a></li>
                        </ul>
                    </li>
                    <li class="submenuItem">
                        <ul class="submenuItemGroup">
                            <li class="submenuItemGroupItem"><a>SUBMENU</a></li>
                            <li class="submenuItemGroupItem"><a>SUBMENU</a></li>
                        </ul>
                    </li>
                    <li class="submenuItem">
                        <ul class="submenuItemGroup">
                            <li class="submenuItemGroupItem"><a>SUBMENU</a></li>
                            <li class="submenuItemGroupItem"><a>SUBMENU</a></li>
                        </ul>
                    </li>
                    <li class="submenuItem">
                        <ul class="submenuItemGroup">
                            <li class="submenuItemGroupItem"><a>SUBMENU</a></li>
                            <li class="submenuItemGroupItem"><a>SUBMENU</a></li>
                        </ul>
                    </li>
                </ul>
            </div>
        </div>
    </nav>
```

I cannot manage the menu exact above image menu. How can I design this? Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

[JSFIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/bhxk0t97/): Here is the code.

```
<nav class="navbar navbar-inverse navbar-fixed-top" role="navigation">
 <div class="container-fluid">
  <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-left">
    <li><a href="#">Link</a></li>

    <li class="dropdown">
      <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown">Home1 <b class="caret"></b></a>
      <ul class="dropdown-menu">

        <li class="dropdown-submenu">
          <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown">Home2</a>
          <ul class="dropdown-menu">
            <li><a  href="#">Action</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Another action</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Something else here</a></li>
            <li class="divider"></li>

            <li>
              <li class="dropdown-submenu">
                <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown">Home2</a>
                <ul class="dropdown-menu">
                  <li><a  href="#">Action</a></li>
                  <li><a href="#">Another action</a></li>
                  <li><a href="#">Something else here</a></li>
                  <li class="divider"></li>
                  <li><a href="#">Separated link</a></li>
                </ul>
              </li>  

            </li>
          </ul>
        </li>

        <li><a href="#">Another action</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Something else here</a></li>
        <li class="divider"></li>
        <li><a href="#">Separated link</a></li>
      </ul>
    </li>

    <li class="dropdown">
      <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown">Home2 <b class="caret"></b></a>
      <ul class="dropdown-menu">
        <li><a href="#">Action</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Another action</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Something else here</a></li>
        <li class="divider"></li>
        <li><a href="#">Separated link</a></li>
      </ul>
    </li>

    <li class="dropdown">
      <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown">Home3 <b class="caret"></b></a>
      <ul class="dropdown-menu">
        <li><a href="#">Action</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Another action</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Something else here</a></li>
        <li class="divider"></li>
        <li><a href="#">Separated link...</a></li>
      </ul>
    </li>

  </ul>
</div>
</nav>
```

If you want more than one level in your menu this code is necessary, else don't add the below code.

```
<style>

.dropdown-submenu {
  position: relative;
}

.dropdown-submenu>.dropdown-menu {
  top: 0;
  left: 100%;
  margin-top: -6px;
  margin-left: -1px;
  -webkit-border-radius: 0 6px 6px 6px;
  -moz-border-radius: 0 6px 6px;
  border-radius: 0 6px 6px 6px;
}

.dropdown-submenu:hover>.dropdown-menu {
  display: block;
}

.dropdown-submenu>a:after {
  display: block;
  content: " ";
  float: right;
  width: 0;
  height: 0;
  border-color: transparent;
  border-style: solid;
  border-width: 5px 0 5px 5px;
  border-left-color: #ccc;
  margin-top: 5px;
  margin-right: -10px;
}

.dropdown-submenu:hover>a:after {
  border-left-color: #fff;
}

.dropdown-submenu.pull-left {
  float: none;
}

.dropdown-submenu.pull-left>.dropdown-menu {
  left: -100%;
  margin-left: 10px;
  -webkit-border-radius: 6px 0 6px 6px;
  -moz-border-radius: 6px 0 6px 6px;
  border-radius: 6px 0 6px 6px;
}

</style>
```

Another way of that menu

```
<nav class="navbar navbar-fixed-top" role="navigation">
<div class="container-fluid" >
<div class = "row" style = "background-color:orange">
<div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-12 col-md-12 col-lg-12">
<ul class="nav navbar-nav">
      <li class="active"><a href="#">Link</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Link</a></li>
      <li class="dropdown">
        <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown">Dropdown <span class="caret"></span></a>
        <ul class="dropdown-menu" role="menu">
          <li><a href="#">Action</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">Another action</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">Something else here</a></li>
          <li class="divider"></li>
          <li><a href="#">Separated link</a></li>
          <li class="divider"></li>
          <li><a href="#">One more separated link</a></li>
        </ul>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</div>

<div class = "row" style = "background-color:green">
  <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-12 col-md-12 col-lg-12">
    <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
      <li class="active"><a href="#">Link</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Link</a></li>
      <li class="dropdown">
        <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown">Dropdown <span class="caret"></span></a>
        <ul class="dropdown-menu" role="menu">
          <li><a href="#">Action</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">Another action</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">Something else here</a></li>
          <li class="divider"></li>
          <li><a href="#">Separated link</a></li>
          <li class="divider"></li>
          <li><a href="#">One more separated link</a></li>
        </ul>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</div>

<div class = "row" style = "background-color:green">
  <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-12 col-md-12 col-lg-12">
    <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
      <li class="active"><a href="#">Link</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Link</a></li>
      <li class="dropdown">
        <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown">Dropdown <span class="caret"></span></a>
        <ul class="dropdown-menu" role="menu">
          <li><a href="#">Action</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">Another action</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">Something else here</a></li>
          <li class="divider"></li>
          <li><a href="#">Separated link</a></li>
          <li class="divider"></li>
          <li><a href="#">One more separated link</a></li>
        </ul>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</div>


</div>
</nav>
```

Comment: Hi @kelgwiin, Thanks your answer, did you see my plunker. There was two step menu whether top or sub. Dropdown menu can be hang from any portion that i mentioned my plunker.

Comment: Hellow @Shoel, I saw your plunker, and the syntax that you use isn't right.You must use the corrent class of each label, else it doesn't work right.

In the label `li` should have the class `dropdown` and the inner list `ul` should have the class `dropdown-menu`, if you want a submenu must write in the class `dropdown-submenu`. You must follow the syntax exactly for it works.

See the official manual for bootstrap [Bootstrap - Navbar](http://getbootstrap.com/components/#navbar)

Comment: Hi @kelgwiin, you are right. but i have to make class topmenu, topmenuItem and so on because bootstrap does not support my menu structure. would you like to make this my exact menu? Thanks

Comment: Mmm I have a doubt about your menu,must the three rows be always visible? So you'd want the three rows like joining three nav bar at the same time.

Comment: Hi  @Shohel again at the end of the solution I attached  the another way of doing the menu, like you want it.

Comment: yes i have three navbar, top navbar and 2 sub navbar. sub navbar container their content like as sine wave curve what i presented my plunker. Here top navbar and sub nav bar height is different. here you can write your own css what i wrote in plunker. you can just fit my plunker example. Thanks

Comment: Thanks your work but my menu will be dynamic, you can just fit my plunker example by write your own css if you agree. here menu will not be left all of menu width will be same width.

Comment: Hi sub menu row can be more than two, so you can not fix this row by two step, please fix my plunker menu by write your own css.

Comment: in that you can duplicate the rows